# Sqlfluff lint error COPY 'unparsable' WITH

Tags: postgresql, sqlfluff

Sqlfluff is giving me an error on this line

```
COPY tableName FROM './var/lib/postgresql/data/short.CSV' WITH CSV QUOTE AS '"';
```

lint error:

```
L:  53 | P:  73 |  PRS | Line 53, Position 73: Found unparsable section: ' WITH
                       | CSV QUOTE AS \'"\''
```

If I run it in the query console it works correctly and if remove "with" lint pass, try with DELIMITER and same error. IDK what happens.

Comment: That is an older syntax of `WITH`. Try: `...WITH (FORMAT CSV, QUOTE '"')...`.

Comment: Should have added that `..,QUOTE '"'...` is redundant as `"` is the default for `CSV` format.

Comment: That is not a question. What kind of answer would you expect? If you think that is a bug, complain to the authors.

Comment: This clearly looks like a bug in sqlfluff